# The library 'package:flutter_gifimage/flutter_gifimage.dart' is legacy, and shouldn't be imported into a null safe library

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, gif, dart-pub

I need the flutter_gifimage package for my project. But I am getting this warning.

If the package is critical for my project and there is no alternative available, should I consider disabling null safety for my entire project.

Is it ok to use package which doesn't support null safety?

Comment: It's not a good idea to use a package that is no longer supported/actively maintained, as is the case here (3 years since an update). You can consider forking it and making it null safe yourself or copying the code you need from it into your app and making it null safe. Otherwise try and find a package that is current and does what you want. Definitely don't make your code non-null safe. That will give you more problems down the road.

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned about running what Flutter calls a mixed-version program, you could either:

- download and import a local copy of `flutter_gifimage` and then
  [migrate that local copy to null-safe](https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety#migrating-incrementally)
- [set your app's language version to version 2.9](https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety#using-the-migration-tool:%7E:text=Alternatively%2C%20set%20the%20language%20version%20in%20the%20entrypoint%E2%80%94the%20file%20that%20contains%20main()%20function%E2%80%94to%202.9.%20In%20Flutter%20apps%2C%20this%20file%20is%20often%20named%20lib/main.dart)

Answer (score 0):

Try another dependency to load gif images like https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_gif